# Listen for just moment of keydown (just when the key changes from up to down)?

Tags: javascript

I tried with keydown and keypress but both fire constantly if the user holds a key. Is there a way to listen only for the when the user presses the key (changes from not pressed to pressed) so that eg: holding the key fires the code once and pressing it, releasing it and pressing it again 2 times?

This is what I'm using to check which keys are down:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e){
    console.log(e.which);
});
```

Comment: `keyup` will only be fired when the key is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, on the first call of `keydown`, unbind the `keydown` handler and then rebind it on `keyup`.

```
// keydown is bound at load
$(document).keydown(function (e){
    // Call function
    doStuff();
});

// keyup rebinds the keydown event.
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
   $(document).keydown(function(e) {
     doStuff();
   });
});

// The function called on keydown does something
// and then unbinds the keydown event
function doStuff() {
   console.log("Doing stuff");
   // And unbind it...
    $(document).unbind('keydown');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbSRu/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using, the good thing is that it can be made to affect all keys or just some of them adding a loop:

```
var keys = {};
var keyPressed = {};
$(document).keydown(function (e){
    if(!keyPressed[e.which]) { keyPressed[e.which] = true; keys[e.which] = true; } // If you add disableKey(e.which) here all keys are listened only once
});
$(document).keyup(function (e){
    delete keys[e.which];
    delete keyPressed[e.which];
});
function disableKey(n) {
    delete keys[n];
}
// Adding this function enables you to disable keys individually (probably have something like this anyway to differenciate keys)
function doStuff() {
    if(keys[65]) { console.log('attack'); disableKey(65); } // Disable key 65
    if(keys[83]) { console.log('jump'); }
    setTimeout(function(){doStuff()},100);
}
doStuff();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbSRu/6/